# Android 3rd party MDM server setup/configuration

Tags: android, android-c2dm, mdm

I am developing an MDM setup for Android to specifically disable the camera ( for android 4.0 ) and to change passwords and wipe data from device.

For background information, I am just a beginner in Android development.

I have read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html and started on doing up a simple app for users to enroll into the device administration.

However, I do not know how to carry on from here.
How do I setup/configure a server to use C2DM to push message to the user?
I do not have any server knowledge too, can anyone please provide tutorials on this?

A step by step guide would be very useful and I have searched and googled for a long time before asking this.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598629/mdm-workflow-in-android/11663694#11663694