# Does locking apps need root access ?

Tags: android

I am working with a developer to develop an app that will provide parents with some control over Android Tablet PC.  This include locking the camera, blocking access to some apps, blocking websites, blocking some advertising networks ..etc.  The developer is telling me the devices need to be rooted.

So can the above be done without rooting the device ?

If must root the device.  Then what does it mean for the Tablet PC user ? And would the app be installed normally?

Comment: [Rooting (Androind)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29) should provide a start .. it means "user beware". I would *not* rely on it for general consumption as support (official or otherwise) varies between devices.

Comment: Hey you need not of root permission see my answer heer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598629/mdm-workflow-in-android/11663694#11663694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that without rooting your device. It requires SuperUser permissions.

Comment: OK.  What will be the implication for the end user (owner of Tablet PC) who is going to install the app.  Any special steps for rooting ?

Comment: There are a variety of tools to root the device, depends on the device. Here's an example of one: SuperOneClick. The only implication for the end user, is to use a tool or an app to root he's device, after that, he's free to install your application and give it SuperUser rights.

Comment: Thanks .. that is very informative answer .. We are planning to sell our own Tablet PC for kids. So we can do the process (Run SuperOneClick, then install the app) in our workshop. Is this correct? .. Also, does the user need to root the device again to install a new update for the app.

Comment: Do you know which will be the devices?

Comment: It is Chinese Android Tablet PC .. we will put our own brand on it.  The manufacturer will put the app while building the device.

Comment: That's awesome. Maybe you can ask the manufacturer to do the rooting task for you, or you can easily do it using some app or tool that are all around the internet! :)